# How to ensure incremental refresh includes the whole day's data?

Tags: powerbi

Suppose my incremental refresh is configured to refresh last 1 day data. This means when the ondemand/scheduled refresh runs, it will pull in the data for that day from 00:00 to time of day when the refresh runs.

Suppose I have scheduled refresh configured at 8am and 8pm. This means that 8am refresh will pull data from 00:00 to 08:00. Then later when the 8pm refresh runs, it will clear the existing data for the day and pull data for 00:00 to 20:00

The next day when the refresh runs then it will pull the data for 00:00 to 08:00. This means that data from 20:00 to 00:00 for each day is lost (not included in the dataset).

Is it advisable to run the refresh at 23:59 so that all data for the day is included? I am concerned because a scheduled refresh is not always guarenteed to run exactly on schedule and it can take upto 1 hour based on resource availability.

But then what if data is entered in the source system at 23:59:45 (45th second). Is there any way to configure the schedule so as to not loose this data?

What is the solution in order to ensure that the whole days data is included in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can simply run the schedule one more time at 00:00 as you mentioned. There are other couple of good practice for your scenario as stated below-

**Option-1:** run the daily schedule 00:05 AM each day and collect data for whole previous day. Collect data with a Date compare like - "**where data = today()-1**". This will always collect previous day's data. This case, end user will always get 1 day older data which is an important concern if it is acceptable or not for your users.

**Option-2:** you can use **Date** values from source and destination to decide which data should be included and excluded from the data transfer process. For example if you have a date column with value like- "**dd/mm/yy hh/mm/ss**", you can first select **MAX(date_from_destination)** and then just select data from source using condition **where date > MAX(date_from_destination)** and insert them to the destination database. This way you can run the schedule as many time as needed. Every time all new data will be pulled and inserted to the destination table.

Comment: For Option1 - Where to enter this "where data = today()-1"? Note that incremental refresh already has the concept of rangestart and rangeend params which are used to filter the table and the values for these params are dynamically set by the Power BI service.

Comment: This need to be set in query using parameter.

Comment: But the rangestart and rangeend are already parameters